# How to retrive data from DB for a selected dropdown value using only JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, jstl

guys i am working on web application in jsp and servlets .. in myjsp.jsp i have a list

```
List<String> sexList = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("sexList"); %>
```

and put it in cumbo box in html tag like this

```
       <td>Gender:</td>
            <td><select name="sex">
                <%for(String i : sexList) { %>
                    <option value="<%=i%>"><%=i %></option><%}%>
                </select>
            </td>
```

but now i want to select the selected item from database using JSTL and i want to know how to return or get this selected item .. any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include it in the form and post it to servlet:

selection.jsp:

```
<form action="display.jsp" method="GET">
  <select name="sex">
    <c:forEach items="${sexList}" var="sex">
       <option value="${sex}">${sex}</option>
    </c:forEach>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

display.jsp

```
<c:set var="sex" value="${param.sex}" scope="page" /> //Gets the selected sex

<sql:query var="person" >
  select * from Person where sex = ?
  <sql:param value="${sex}" />
</sql:query>
```

Comment: i want to use JSTL :)

Comment: how to return the selected item please in JSTL??

Comment: Include it in a form and create a submit button. When user select a gender and click submit button, it will send post request to servelet. In your servlet, you can get the selected gender using "request.getParameter("sex")". Updated the answer

Comment: i understand you well :) but the problem is that i want all the operations occur in the jsp whithout using servlets as i want to select data from database using the selected items from combo box using JSTL

Comment: Oh I see. Your trying to send parameter to another jsp. I updated the answer, but  didn't check it. It should work, try the updated answer. Let me know if that what you trying to do.

Comment: you wrote sex=? what that means ?? by the way i want to select person whose sex is the same selected value in combo box .. doesnt that sex=? make this or not

Comment: that's exactly what it's doing. "?" is a symbol to indicate it's a parameter. Yes, above code is doing exactly that. In the selection.jsp you are selecting a sex and click submit. In your display.jsp, you get the selected sex and running query where sex=?.

Comment: Can you post the exception?